# image taken from gallery is unable to set in image view

Tags: java, android

I am taking image from camera as well as from gallery,after getting the image, I want to show the image in imageview.

Image that is captured by camera successfully is shown in imageview but when I want to select it from gallery it does not show the image and it also does not show any error. It was working properly but later I add camera feature in activity, it's not working well.

```
public class DoReport extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText subject,detail;
    private ImageView pic;
    private ImageView iv;
    private Spinner  depart;
    private String depat,sub,det;
    //for image
    private Bitmap selectedImage;
    public static String image;
    private Uri imageUri;
    public final static int PHOTO_FROM_MEMORY_REQUESTED = 10;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    String userChoosenTask;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_do_report);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
        detail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail);
        depart = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Depat_Edit);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImgView);
    }
    public void onBackClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,UserView.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,UserView.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    //to pic the image from galery

    //this is new <code>
    public void imgBtn(View v) {
        selectImage();
    }

    private void updateSelectedPicture(Uri uri) {
        try {
            imageUri = uri;
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

            iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(selectedImage));
            image=encode(selectedImage);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e("File not found", "Cannot find background file under received URI");
        }
    }

    public static String encode(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immagex=image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
        return imageEncoded;
    }

    public void submit(View v) {
        depat=depart.getSelectedItem().toString();
        sub=subject.getText().toString();
        det=detail.getText().toString();
        if(sub.isEmpty()) {
            subject.setError("subject is required");
        } else if(det.isEmpty()) {
            detail.setError("subject is required");
        } else {
            login_database(depat, sub, det, image);
        }
    }

    private void login_database(final String depat, final String sub,final String det,final String pic) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Static.user_connect,//changes required
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if ((response.contains("successful"))) {
                            Toast.makeText(DoReport.this, "Successful Submitted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent (DoReport.this,UserView.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(DoReport.this, "Some error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//changes required
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(DoReport.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("ERROR", toString());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("key", "3");//changes required
                map.put("Depat", depat);
                map.put("Detail", det);
                map.put("Pic", pic);
                map.put("Subject", sub);
                map.put("U_id",Static.id);
                return map;
            }
        };
        queue.add(request);
    }

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    code for selecting image from camera or gallery

    *////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if( requestCode== REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            try {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    iv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                    image = encode(imageBitmap);//this line is added to encode
                } else if (requestCode == PHOTO_FROM_MEMORY_REQUESTED && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    updateSelectedPicture(data.getData());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){ Toast.makeText(DoReport.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }
    }

    ///////////////it will show the dialogue box
    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DoReport.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(DoReport.this);
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Take Photo";
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Choose from Library";
                    gallery();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    public void gallery() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, PHOTO_FROM_MEMORY_REQUESTED);
    }
}
```

Comment: iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

Comment: it is not working

Comment: iv.setimageurl is not working that u are telling me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only change onActivityResult method remove else if block form id condition like below code...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode== REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        try {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                iv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                image = encode(imageBitmap);//this line is added to encode
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e){ Toast.makeText(DoReport.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
    else if (requestCode == PHOTO_FROM_MEMORY_REQUESTED && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        updateSelectedPicture(data.getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.it is working now.else if condition was withen if statement

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to set a rounding photo from gallery or camera into ImageButton and it works perfectly :

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btnValidate,btnCancel,imgProfile;
    TextView tvEditPhoto;
    RoundImage roundedImage;
    private String userChoosenTask;
    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back_btn);
        btnValidate = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_validate_btn);
        imgProfile = findViewById(R.id.user_profile_photo_edit);
        tvEditPhoto = findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name_edit);

        //Rounding image
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.profile);
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
        imgProfile.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        imgProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

        tvEditPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PictureUtility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Oups ! vous n'avez pas la permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result= PictureUtility.checkPermission(EditProfileActivity.this);
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //resize picture
        Bitmap bmw = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 120, 120, false);
        //rounding picture
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(bmw);
        imgProfile.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Bitmap bmw = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 120, 120, false);
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(bmw);
        imgProfile.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    }

}
```

In your code, try to add createScaledBitmap to resize your photo like this:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                //add this line and use the new bitmap resized

                Bitmap imageBitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap , 120, 120, false);
                iv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmapResized );
                image = encode(imageBitmapResized );//this line is added to encode
            } else if (requestCode == PHOTO_FROM_MEMORY_REQUESTED && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                updateSelectedPicture(data.getData());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

You should check if selectedImage -the bitmap-  is null.

I bet `selectedImage==null`.

This happens if the bitmap would become too big for available memory.

You should scale it down while loading from stream.

Remember: from the camera you only obtain a thumbnail. Thats the difference.

Comment: the same code is runnig in my other application and i am uloading the same image,but here it is not showing the image

Comment: `You should check if selectedImage -the bitmap- is null.`. Why dont you report?

Comment: how can i check that?